# How to make slide like homepage of adidas.com with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

adidas.com so cool !!!!!!!!!!

why not with jQuery, CSS & HTML?

How div with different height & width together fill up div container when height & width are get random from database?

Someones help me?

Comment: I don't think it's random at all - it looks like meticulously constructed and pre-determined, with each panel constrained to move only in certain directions (up/down or left/right). You can simulate the entire thing in jQuery, but you do need to design each transition and code it specifically

Comment: And it's a usability nightmare. Try to get your mouse pointer over one of the smaller areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be quite difficult to reproduce in jQuery but there is a jquery plugin called 
jQuery Masonry that arranges elements vertically then horizontally according to a grid.

http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry

You could then start to apply sliding effects to each block element using a the hover function and css. There's a good tutorial here

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-day-7

Comment: I've got it going, but I'm having trouble getting the grid to dynamically resize width and height. Here's what I've got as well as my stack question if you can offer any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699373/getting-the-protrusion-and-collision-data-from-jquery-collision - Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

An open source project has been started to create a jQuery plugin to achieve a similar effect to the one Adidas had on their site:

Find out more information at: http://github.com/jasonenglish/jquery-flex

Comment: Is it possible to place images randomly like jquery-masonry?

Comment: I've been thinking about how to allow similar plugins to create the layout. I'll create a demo of Flex using Masonry to automate the layout creation. I'll post the demo here when it's up.